# populating items into dropdownlist instead of table in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

Currently i am populating the table with the items using for each , below is the code :
Updated: _FilterSpecsBox.cshtml

```
         @model CatalogPagingFilteringModel.SpecificationFilterModel
           @{
         var renderedAttributeNames = new List<string>();
          }  
       <div class="product-spec-filter">
       @* <div class="title">
            @T("Filtering.SpecificationFilter")
        </div>*@
        @*<div class="clear">
        </div>*@
        @if (Model.NotFilteredItems.Count > 0)
        {
            <div>
                <table class="filter">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.NotFilteredItems)
                    {
                        if (!renderedAttributeNames.Contains(item.SpecificationAttributeName))
                        {
                            renderedAttributeNames.Add(item.SpecificationAttributeName);
                            <tr class="group">
                                <td>
                                    @item.SpecificationAttributeName
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                        <tr class="item">
                            <td>
                                **<a href="@item.FilterUrl">@item.SpecificationAttributeOptionName</a>**
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        }
        @if (Model.AlreadyFilteredItems.Count > 0)
        {
            <div>
                <div class="title">
                    @T("Filtering.SpecificationFilter.CurrentlyFilteredBy")
                </div>
                <table class="filter">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.AlreadyFilteredItems)
                    {
                        <tr class="filtereditem">
                            <td>
                                <b>@(item.SpecificationAttributeName):</b> @item.SpecificationAttributeOptionName
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="remove-filter">
                <a href="@Model.RemoveFilterUrl" class="remove-product-spec-filter">@T("Filtering.SpecificationFilter.Remove")</a>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

I want to populate the @item.FilterUrl in the dropdownlist , can anyone provide any assistance of how to achieve this.

Updated: _filter.cshtml

```
 @*filtering*@
@if (Model.PagingFilteringContext.PriceRangeFilter.Enabled ||
    Model.PagingFilteringContext.SpecificationFilter.Enabled)
{
    <div class="product-filters">
        <div class="filter-title">
            <span>Filter Products By Analytes</span>
        </div>
     @*   <div class="filter-item">
            @Html.Partial("_FilterPriceBox", Model.PagingFilteringContext.PriceRangeFilter, new ViewDataDictionary())
        </div>*@
        <div class="filter-item">
            @Html.Partial("_FilterSpecsBox", Model.PagingFilteringContext.SpecificationFilter, new ViewDataDictionary())
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@model CatalogPagingFilteringModel.SpecificationFilterModel

<div class="product-spec-filter">
    @if (Model.NotFilteredItems.Count > 0)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("NotFilteredItem", new SelectList(Model.NotFilteredItems, "SpecificationAttributeName", "SpecificationAttributeName"))
        </div>
    }
    @if (Model.AlreadyFilteredItems.Count > 0)
    {
        <div class="title">
            @T("Filtering.SpecificationFilter.CurrentlyFilteredBy")
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("FilteredItem", new SelectList(Model.AlreadyFilteredItems, "SpecificationAttributeName", "SpecificationAttributeOptionName"))
        </div>
        <div class="remove-filter">
            <a href="@Model.RemoveFilterUrl" class="remove-product-spec-filter">@T("Filtering.SpecificationFilter.Remove")</a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: But i cant get the filteration working now , in the above code it was doing filteration when any attribute was selected

Comment: On the centre left, Filter products by analyte

Comment: @Mr A, the filtering is something that you should do in the controller, not in the view. The controller should prepare the NotFilteredItems and AlreadyFilteredItems properties of your view model so that all the view has to do is use them as is. Otherwise if you start doing filtering and stuff in the view, you are violating the MVC pattern. The view should not manipulate any data. It is there only to display the data that has been fed by the controller under the form of a view model. So if your view model is not suitable then adapt it and do the heavy work in the controller.